# Why won't zsh run npm scripts

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio, node-modules

My default SHELL is `zsh`, when I run `npm start` inside react folder it doesn't seem to work,

```
Starting the development server...

node:events:371
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn brave ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn brave',
  path: 'brave',
  spawnargs: [ 'http://localhost:3001' ]
}
```

On the other hand, if I use the bash terminal or vs terminal (bash kind) it does work properly